# Output from LM35 temperature sensor varies wildly

Tags: temperature, lm35

I've seen other posts on this board which related to output from the LM35 sensor, but mine seem to be more 'extreme' than anything else I've seen.

I've connected the pins as is commonly suggested - left hand to 5v, middle A0, and right to GRN and used the folowing code

```cpp
const int sensorPin = A0;

float sensorValue;
float voltageOut;

float temperatureC;
float temperatureF;


void setup() {
  
pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
    
}

void loop() {
  
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  voltageOut = (sensorValue * 5000) / 1024;
  temperatureC = voltageOut / 10;
    
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print("\n");
  //Serial.print(temperatureC);
  //Serial.print("\n");
  
  delay(10000);
}
```

I commented out the temperature printing lines to avoid the error being in the conversion.

Leaving it run for a while I get the following

```
756.00
0.00
27.00
7.00
16.00
64.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
6.00
82.00
20.00
10.00
3.00
38.00
0.00
73.00
0.00
78.00
68.00
0.00
80.00
0.00
2.00
29.00
48.00
10.00
0.00
23.00
64.00
27.00
0.00
79.00
0.00
0.00
56.00
60.00
9.00
0.00
15.00
82.00
2.00
2.00
40.00
76.00
18.00
43.00
17.00
74.00
49.00
21.00
14.00
0.00
74.00
0.00
3.00
81.00
3.00
55.00
20.00
0.00
41.00
72.00
40.00
0.00
54.00
27.00
```

Our house is fairly stable in temperature, and the sensor is in a location out of anything which could drastically alter the temperature.

If anybody can suggest a reason for this I'd be grateful.

Comment: Nothing obviously bad with the code. Try replacing the LM35 with a potentiometer (pretty much same connections - one side to VCC, other side to ground, middle to A0) or just a voltage divider and see if the code works.

Comment: Thanks for the great piece of contructive thinking! I put a potentiometer onto it and it was steady as a rock, which makes me think my problem is therefore some really, really, shoddy LM35s.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, how do you define `left hand` when you holding the chip? bottom view or top view? Assuming you means TO-92 packaging.

Comment: not the problem now, but change `sensorValue * 5000` to `sensorValue * 5000L`

Comment: Assuming the LM35 is fine you probably habe faulty connections. Most probably mixed up top/bottom view of the sensor or a connection is unreliable.

Comment: Ihcheung - 'left hand' with the writing towards me :-)
Juraj - thanks, when I get the connections sorted I'll try that
Sim Son - I'm suspecting the sensors to be honest, they were supercheap ones. I've got a different brand on order which I suspect will improve things.